# Localization of Hom in an advanced setting

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A,\,B$ rings and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Let $g:A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism which makes $B$ into a finitely generated $A$-algebra. Now we can regard the $A$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,M)$ as a $B$-module via
$$ (b\cdot\phi)(b') = \phi(b\cdot b')\quad \forall\, b,\,b' \in B \text{ and } \phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(B,M). $$
Now I want to localize the $B$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,M)$ at a prime $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(B)$. What does the result look like?

For some instances we have that localization and Hom commute in the sense of 
$$ S^{-1}\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}B,S^{-1}M)$$
where $S \subset A$ is a multiplicative set in $A$ and the above is a localization of $A$-modules.

Do we obtain in the above setting a similar result? I conjecture that (maybe under some additional requirements on $A,B,M$) the following is the result:

> Let $\mathfrak p = g^{-1}(P) \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$.
>   $$ \left(\operatorname{Hom}_A(B,M)\right)_P \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{A_{\mathfrak p}}(B_P,M_{\mathfrak p}).$$

Do you have ideas to prove this (don't forget about making additional assumptions) or any straight counterexamples?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: One basic theorem in these situations is, if $K$ is a finitely presented module over $A$, and $S\subset A$ is a multiplicatively closed subset, then $S^{-1}\mathrm{Hom}_A(K,M)=\mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}K,S^{-1}M)$. So, for example, if you assume $A$ is Noetherian and $B$ a finitely generated $A$-module, then you do have such an isomorphism for $S\subset A$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, I am aware of that and I even mentioned it in my post. And this is in some sense making me conjecture that we obtain a similar result as stated above.

Comment: Are you sure $S^{-1}\mathrm{Hom}_A(B,M)=\mathrm{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}B, S^{-1}M)$ without any hypothesis on $B$? The result I mentioned would say yes if $B$ is a finitely presented $A$-module. Otherwise, I think you will run into trouble.